# Angular Material: Shake MatDialog

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Is it possible to add a custom CSS shake animation to a Material MatDialog (e.g. if you entered wrong infos in a Form-Dialog)?

Since the dialog is instantiated via the MatDialog service, I can not add a ngClass (with a condition to add and remove the shake style) directly to the template.

Dialog creation looks like this:

```
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { 
    this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {});
  }
```

The shake style (in the MyDialog Component) like this:

```
:host#my-dialog  {
    &.shake-dialog {
        animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both !important;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)!important;
        backface-visibility: hidden!important;
        perspective: 1000px!important;
        overflow: hidden !important;

        @keyframes shake {
            10%, 90% {
                transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0)!important;
            }
            20%, 80% {
                transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0)!important;
            }
            30%, 50%, 70% {
                transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0)!important;
            }
            40%, 60% {
                transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0)!important;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried to add/remove the shake animation via HostBinding. I managed to dynamically add/remove the shake-class this way to my dialog component, however, it takes no effect since all webkit styles are kind of overridden. Inspect in Chrome:

[image: Chrome Inspect]

Even though I added an ID to increase the specificity, the shaking styles are not applied. Is this due to the nature of a MatDialog?

Is there any way, I could get this to work? Or did I maybe choose the wrong approach in the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the dialog to be in a custom module, where `NoopAnimations` is used (it disables animations).

Once the animations are disabled, you can override the overlay. Selector is

```
mat-dialog-container.mat-dialog-container {}
```